# Why childNodes[i] in function return undefined but alert an object?

Tags: javascript, dom

Well, i'm writting my own getElementByClassName and this is my problem :

```
function getElementByClassName(elemento,clase){
        var i = 0;
        if(elemento.hasChildNodes()){
            while(elemento.childNodes[i]){
                if(elemento.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3){
                    if(elemento.childNodes[i].className == clase){
                        return elemento.childNodes[i];  // <---- This is my problem, change to alert
                    }
                    else {
                    getElementByClassName(elemento.childNodes[i],clase);
                    }
                }

                i++
            }
        }
}

var div = getElementByClassName(document.body,"foo");

alert(div);
```

It alerts undefined, but if i put ( in function) alert this alerts [objectHTMLDivElement] and undefined, so why this returns undefined if this recognize that's a [objectHTMLDivElement] with alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the reason why your implementation is not working is because you're recursively calling your function in the `else` clause and doing nothing with the return value. That's why your code is finding the object, but it's never getting returned.

This is a slightly reworked version of yours, but there are also other limitations to your approach, one being elements with multiple classes will not be found (i.e. `<div class="foo bar">` will not be returned). Unless you're just doing this as a learning exercise, I suggest going with an existing implementation, like the link in Yoni's answer.

```
function getElementByClassName(elemento, clase)
{
    var i = 0;
    if (elemento.hasChildNodes())
    {
        while (elemento.childNodes[i])
        {
            if (elemento.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3)
            {
                if (elemento.childNodes[i].className == clase)
                    return elemento.childNodes[i];
                else
                {
                    var result = getElementByClassName(elemento.childNodes[i], clase);
                    if (result != null)
                        return result;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!, and yes, this is for learning, I will study your code.